# Ajax chat page freezes browser window

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chat, freeze

I have website. I coded chat page with jQuery AJAX. there are 3 ajax call.

1. AJAX request for send new chat text,
2. AJAX request for detect user is typing
3. AJAX request for detect new messages.

I use JSON to send and receive low data for chat. I used the best technology for chat with AJAX, but the web page freezes when I type a message into the input box or scroll up and down in the history of chat. I can't understand why the page is freezing.

First I was fetching all chat history. I changed it so it only fetches new messages if there are any, but this did not solve my problem.

Second, I tried setting `async=true` or *false* - this does not solve my problem. It must work correctly without freezing but it freezes.

Screenshots are below.

[image: firebug ajax calls]
[image: chat window]

Comment: Post the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Are you queuing your AJAX requests?

You can use `$.Deferred` if you're using jQuery, use `.queue()`, or directly place your AJAX functions sequentially within a function. Alternately, you might need to set/tweak `setTimeout` on the functions.

A rather awesome developer (who isn't me) [developed an ajaxQueue plugin](http://gnarf.net/2011/06/21/jquery-ajaxqueue/) that handles these events well. A working jsfiddle example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1337/9TG8t/86/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, I can imagine there are 2 possible problems on the implementation.

1. You have an user-is-typing feature which means that your must have bind a key event (either key-up, key-down, key-pressed) If you did not debounce your event handler, there will be a request for every character typed and may freeze the browser. There are some easy-to-use plugin for debounce function for jQuery. Here is an example http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
2. DOM manipulation is extremely time consuming in all browser. Unlike Angular and React, jQuery did not optimize it for you. You have to minimize adding / updating / deleting DOM elements. Say you fetch messages, check is there any change / is they exist for each of them, before you do anything in the DOM tree.

The `async` option of `$.ajax()` is default to be true based on the [document](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You do not need to add it by yourself.